# Read data from multiple json files in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, history

**What I trying to Do**

I am saving each change in database in each json file, now I am trying to retrieve data from multiple JSON files to show history of each record.

**My Problem**

But data retrieving is taking lot of time to post results.

You think it's a good idea or in a Laravel can do it in an easier way??

Comment: do you think we can help you without posting any code

Comment: It is related to retrieving data related to JSON files using Laravel 5.4 . I don't think code is required to suggest the solution

Comment: Why you store these changes to multiple JSON files? Keep them in the same database. There are libraries to address audit.

Comment: I may get 1000's of records because I want to store data upto next 5 years. So If I lost that file then 5 years old data will be gone. So storing in separate files instead of single file